# embedded font flash.text.engine

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, fonts

I've completely run out of ideas on this. It follows, and is part of my previous question:

[embedding a font in a swf using as3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12763516/embedding-a-font-in-a-swf-using-as3/12807110#12807110)

I just don't seem to be able to get the flash.text.engine to use my embedded font. NB the font has to be loaded into the application (as embedded in swf) after the user has chosen the two languages  (for translation to and from). There seems to be a little info implying that it is now necessary to use the fontswf application which is in the sdk. I have tried this and produced loadable swf files but I can't find any info on how these are then loaded (i.e. the getDefinition and registerFont bits below don't work as there are no classes in these swf) and applied to text.engine objects. The source for the embedding is in my answer to my question above. This is a test as3 which demonstrates how it doesn't work!

```
package 
{
import flash.display.Loader;
import flash.display.Shape;
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.text.engine.ElementFormat;
import flash.text.engine.FontDescription;
import flash.text.engine.TextBlock;
import flash.text.engine.TextLine;
import flash.text.engine.TextElement;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.text.Font;

public class Main extends Sprite 
{
    private var loader:Loader;
    private var tl:TextLine;

    public function Main():void 
    {
        loader = new Loader();
        loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,fontLoaded);
        loader.load(new URLRequest("EnglishF.swf"));
    }

    private function fontLoaded(evt:Event):void {
        var FontClass:Class
        FontClass = evt.target.applicationDomain.getDefinition("EnglishF") as Class;
        try {
            Font.registerFont(FontClass.myFont);
            trace("successfully loaded " + FontClass); 
            // gives 'successfully loaded EnglishF'
        } catch (err:Error) {}
        var fontList:Array = Font.enumerateFonts();
        for (var i:int = 0; i < fontList.length; i++) {
            trace(fontList[i].fontName, fontList[i].fontType); 
            // gives 'EnglishF embeddedCFF'
        }
        var block:TextBlock = new TextBlock();
        var font:FontDescription = new FontDescription("EnglishF");
        var formt:ElementFormat = new ElementFormat(font, 30);
        trace(FontDescription.isFontCompatible("EnglishF","normal","normal"), formt.fontDescription.fontName); 
        // gives 'true EnglishF'
        formt.color = 0x882233;
        var span:TextElement = new TextElement("Hello World. This is certainly NOT in the Font provided!", formt);
        block.content = span;
        tl = block.createTextLine();
        tl.x = 10;
        tl.y = tl.ascent + 10;
        addChild(tl);
    }
}
}
```

Am I doing anything wrong, or is this impossible?

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this will help.  Under this line:

```
var font:FontDescription = new FontDescription("EnglishF");
```

add the following line:

```
font.fontLookup = FontLookup.EMBEDDED_CFF;
```

This will let the text framework know that you're using a CFF font (used in the new text framework), instead of a regular embedded font (used in TextFields).

Hope this helps.

Jordan